# How do I write a generic function to delete any valid pointer?

Tags: c++

Following is my code snippet. I am trying to write generic function to check whether pointer is valid and deleting it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct testStruct 
{
    int nVal;
    _TCHAR tcVal[256];
    testStruct() 
    {
        wmemset(tcVal, 0, _countof(tcVal));
    }
};

void deletePointer(void *obj)
{
    if (obj)
    {
        delete obj;
        obj = NULL;
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    testStruct *obj = new testStruct;
    wstring *strVal = new wstring();
    vector<wstring> *vecVal = new vector<wstring>;
    map<wstring,wstring> *mapVal = new map<wstring, wstring>;

    //My business logic goes here.
    

    //Finally after all business logic, clearing allocated memory.
    deletePointer(obj);
    deletePointer(strVal);
    deletePointer(vecVal);
    deletePointer(mapVal);

    return 0;
}
```

While I am not facing any compilation or runtime error, just wanted to confirm, if this is the right way to check and delete multiple points. I don't want to check individual pointer whether it is valid or not before deleting. So calling generic function.

Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Compilation and runtime errors are not present. Just need confirmation, if this is right way or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: That's C++, not C.

Comment: Should it be `template <typename T>void deletePointer(T*&obj)`?

Comment: But smart pointer would be more appropriate... (Or even object directly (`std::vector` doesn't need to be new-ed)).

Comment: There isn't really a way to check if a pointer is "valid" in the sense that it points to a region of memory that corresponds to a live object and it's safe to call `delete` on it. `if (obj)` checks if `obj` is or is not `nullptr`, but that _does not_ tell you it's meaningful to call `delete obj;`. You may need to step back and re-evaluate the larger goal that this code is intended to help you accomplish.

Comment: The allocation of memory can be based on certain conditions. But at the end I want to delete only if that is really allocated. Without that if I invoke delete, it will lead to crash I guess.

Comment: What’s wrong with `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Hi @user3840170, the problem is with legacy applications which runs on VS2008.

Comment: If you don’t want people ask you that repeatedly, better add it into the question somewhere visible.

Comment: @knkumar93 *if this is right way or is there a better way to do this.* -- The right way is to write your program correctly, where you don't need hacks to determine if a pointer is valid.  If the pointer is invalid, then that is a bug in your code that you're trying to cover up.  You should be able to simply do a `delete obj;` with no check needed to see if it is null (the null check in your code is unnecessary anyway).

Comment: Calling delete on void* will only release the memory held by object, and won't call its destructor, this can put all your program in corrupted state and cause memory leaks, for example std::string releases pointer to string in destructor, and if you delete it via void*, the memory allocated by std::string will never be released

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, it's both incorrect and unnecessary

If your compiler doesn't report error on this code, crank up warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/7ranoEnMa. Deleting a `void*` is Undefined Behaviour, you cannot predict what will be the result. If it's currently not crashing, it will likely crash at some random other use when you will least expect it.

It's unnecessary, because it's perfectly fine to `delete nullptr;` and your function only checks against that. If you wanted to check if the pointer is actually valid like Nathan Pierson suggests in comment (and you don't assign `nullptr` to them consistently), that's not possible. You are responsible for your memory management, no `if` can help if you don't do that correctly throughout the program.

And it's also not necessary, because memory management is already done for you. Containers shouldn't be ever allocated on the heap. Simply do

```
    wstring strVal;
    vector<wstring> vecVal;
    map<wstring,wstring> mapVal;
```

And drop the pointers. C++ containers do all the magic by themselves and are generally small by themselves (`sizeof(std::vector)` is usually `3*sizeof(void*)`).

Assuming you really need `testStruct` on the heap rather than in automatic storage, you should use a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<testStruct> obj = std::make_unique<testStruct>();
```

There, it's created, allocated on the heap and will be automatically deleted when `obj` ends its scope. You don't have to worry about `delete`ing anything anymore.

---

If you really want to have a function that `delete`s objects manually, it should look like this:

```
template <typename T>
void deletePointer(T*& obj)
{
    delete obj;
    obj = nullptr;
}
```

It keeps the type of the pointer to be deleted and updates passed pointer with `nullptr`, so it won't be invalid later on.